# Export all data from table to csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, export

I would like to ask for help in regards to exporting data from dataTable to a csv file.

I already tried using npm table2csv but what it does is it only export data from the current table.

```
<button id="export-csv" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Export</button>

$("#export-csv").click(function() {
    $("table").table2csv({
        separator: ',',
        newline: '\n',
        quoteFields: true,
        exludeRows: 'thead tr',
        filename: 'filename_' + exportDate + '.csv'
    });
});
```

What I would like to do is export data from the current table including those data from the succeeding pages. Like if I have 200 data the table only shows 100 data, when I export it the csv file should contain all 200 data.

Thank you in advance to anyone that could share their insights.

Comment: where is the other 100 present?

Comment: You will need to make a call to your data source to retrieve all of the records.  In that case might as well just make an endpoint that returns the est as csv and return that to the client.